# RAILS Plugin Streamlined Being Used?

Tags: plugins

It looked like Plugin Streamlined came in with a bang then I am not seeing much on it. Is anyone using it? Is it worth looking at?

Answer (score 0):

I used it in nearly everything I wrote with Rails and found it unsurpassed by any other scaffolding plugin I tried. Give it a try, and maybe look at the tutorials first.
have fun